# iOS - "Too Many Contexts" error?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmanagedobject

My App (under development, iOS 5.1) occasionally crashes with the following message:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Too many contexts. No space in contextList.'`

Googling this message returns zero results.

I'm using a single NSManagedObjectContext taken from the AppDelegate singleton, simple and straightforward, no tricks.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to see where it's breaking at? Depending on your debugger, you could use info symbol or im loo -a with the first small hex value in the crash log.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably got some object recursing into itself during construction, probably in `alloc` or `init`.

You can also set an exception breakpoint for "All Exceptions" and see what gets caught...